# Spring batch Unique name for mutiple file writer

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am using spring batch in my application. I am using multithreading using spring batch at step level .

Below is my configuration:

```
<step id="testStep">
      <tasklet 
        task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="5">
        <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer"
          commit-interval="10">
        </chunk>
         </tasklet>
    </step>

    <bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="file:${output.file.location.directory}/<<<NEED TO PASS CURRENT EXECUTING THREAD NAME>>>" />
        <property name="appendAllowed" value="true"></property>
        <property name="lineAggregator" ref="aggregator" />
  </bean>
```

So in resource property of flatfileitemWriter , i need to pass current executing thread name, so that each thread wil write in a separate unique file.

I can able to get the current executing thread name in writer class but dont know how to get the same in the spring confirguration file .

Any idea to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use [spEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html); with this scripting language you can use standard java method and to retrive current thread name the syntax is 
`#{T(java.lang.Thread).getCurrentThread().getName()}`.

In a more clear way use a [StepExecutionListener.beforeStep()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html#beforeStep-org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution-) injecting the current thread name into step execution context (eg. `currentThreadName` key) and retrieve from step xml config in the standard way

```
<property name="resource" value="file:${output.file.location.directory}/#{stepExecutionContext['currentThreadName']}" />
```